# Jquery question about attribute manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and I can't figure out a solution for my problem.
I'm using jQuery easytooltip on some SVG objects in my website. Everything is working fine but I need to change some attributes of the tooltip on runtime. My document.ready function is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("polygon").easyTooltip({
        tooltipId: "easyTooltip2",
        content: 'hello'
    });
});
```

I want to be able,( on mouseover on my polygons) to read out attributes from my polygons and pass them into the content attribute, which is showed when the tooltip is showing... How can I access the content value to change it on runtime?

my plugin code now looks like this:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.content = function (_content) {

    $(this).easyToolTip({ content: _content }) 
 };

$.fn.easyTooltip = function (options) {

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {
        xOffset: 10,
        yOffset: 25,
        tooltipId: "easyTooltip",
        clickRemove: false,
        content: "",
        useElement: ""
    };


    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var content;


    this.each(function () {
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        $(this).hover(function (e) {
            content = (options.content != "") ? options.content : title;
            content = (options.useElement != "") ? $("#" + options.useElement).html() : content;
            $(this).attr("title", "");
            if (content != "" && content != undefined) {
                $("body").append("<div id='" + options.tooltipId + "'>" + content + "</div>");
                $("#" + options.tooltipId)
                    .css("position", "absolute")
                    .css("top", (e.pageY - options.yOffset) + "px")
                    .css("left", (e.pageX + options.xOffset) + "px")
                    .css("display", "none")
                    .fadeIn("slow")
            }
        },
        function () {
            $("#" + options.tooltipId).remove();
            $(this).attr("title", title);
        });
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            $("#" + options.tooltipId)
                .css("top", (e.pageY - options.yOffset) + "px")
                .css("left", (e.pageX + options.xOffset) + "px")
        });
        if (options.clickRemove) {
            $(this).mousedown(function (e) {
                $("#" + options.tooltipId).remove();
                $(this).attr("title", title);
            });
        }
    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `.live()`:

```
$("polygon").live("mouseover", function() {

     $("polygon").easyTooltip({
           tooltipId: "easyTooltip2",
           content: 'hello'
     });

});
```

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I'm already using a onmousover function,written in javascript. In this function I think I have to add something like: $("easyTooltip2").content = "changedContent"; Is that somehow possible?

Comment: @Paperjam you should use mouseover and not onmouseover

Comment: @john It's possible. You can create your own jQuery plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) by doing something like this: `$.fn.content = function(_content) { $(this).easyToolTip({ content: _content}) }`. I've not had a chance to test this, but I think this might put you in the right direction.

Comment: @Nicola Thanks. It's way past my bed time heh.

Comment: ive added $("easyTooltip2").content("changed"); in my javascript onmouseover function but there is an error that tells me that it doesnt support the content function.
Ive also added your function in my plugin code:(see edit on my original post)

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/k3YxZ/1/. Make sure your `$.fn` code comes before your other code. Order of script loading should go jQuery, Easy Tooltip, `$.fn`, then the rest.

Comment: @paperjam i see the result "Test". But i think it's not what i want to do, i just need to change the content variable from my jqery code via a normal javascript function. The content attribute is the text which finally is displayed in the tooltip window, i need to change the content to show different text over every polygon(text will be depending on the polygon's attribute like "id"...)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$("polygon").mouseover(function() {

     $("polygon").easyTooltip({
           tooltipId: "easyTooltip2",
           content: 'changedContent'
     });

});
```

this would recreate the tooltip: a better option would be to modify only the content, i'll look into the api to see if it's possible. (it's not possible to do with the api provided by the plugin i think, re-create the tooltip)